# Can I run a Windows Powershell command matching all files in the current directory and all subdirectories?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, wildcard

My file structure looks like this:

```
maindir/
  - subdir/
      - file1.ts
      - file2.ts
  - file3.ts
  - file4.ts
```

I'm trying to build typescript interfaces using [ts-interface-builder](https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-builder), and I want to match and build all 4 `file*.ts` files. (ts-interface-builder just builds the types, this question is mainly about the matching pattern / wildcards in Windows Powershell since I'm used to Unix).

I'm currently using this command:

`npx ts-interface-builder ./maindir/*.ts`

But this only builds `file3.ts` and `file4.ts`.
I could use a slightly different command:

`npx ts-interface-builder ./maindir/*/*.ts`

But it only builds `file1.ts` and `file2.ts`.

I tried researching Windows Powershell wildcards but wasn't able to figure it out.
Is there a **single** command I could use to build all 4 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `npx` command is executed by / from PowerShell:

```sh
npx ts-interface-builder (Get-ChildItem ./maindir -Recurse -Filter *.ts).FullName
```

See also: The [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet.